# How to disable emoji keyboard on iOS 13?

Tags: swift, keyboard, ios13

I have an issue with disabling the emoji keyboard on iOS 13.
before iOS 13 I could easily hide the emoji keyboard by
`textField.keyboardType = .asciiCapable`
Of course I still can do the same on iOS 13, it will remove the emoji keyboard option from the keyboard selection list:

[image]

but with the same setup, the emoji button will be available on the keyboard itself:

[image]

The problem is that it happens if only the user has 4 or more keyboards at the same time. And it only happens on iOS 13 and up, using iPhone X and up, not before that.
So to wrap up: the emoji keyboard will always be hidden from the list of keyboards by using `textField.keyboardType = .asciiCapable` but won't be hidden on the keyboard itself if the user has 4 keyboards (in this case: English, Danish, Swedish and Emoji). and of course it's a problem only on iPhone x and up because of the new design.
Does anyone know how I can completely disable or remove the emoji option on keyboard?

P.S. I'm testing on iOS 13.3 and 12.4, iPhone X and up, using Xcode 11.3.1

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No, I just filter the text input instead, so even if the user press the emojies nothing will show up.

Answer (score 7):

```
txtField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable;
```

Comment: I have already mentioned that I have this code and it doesn't work under the situation that I have explained in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution I have found on the Swift Arcade channel:

```
yourTextField.keyboardType = .asciiCapable
```